# Combine rows from a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I wish to combine rows from a given subquery. I also wish to, if possible, hold the subquery in a variable. Without holding in a variable, I get error since there are more than 1 result.

```
DECLARE @myquery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @myquery = (select cm.USER_ID
                from mytable cm 
                where cm.USER_ID = 'A' or USER_ID = 'B'
                group by cm.USER_ID
                having count(1) > 1);

select string_agg(cast(@myquery as NVARCHAR(MAX)) , ', ') as DuplicateList 
from mytable cm
```

Comment: Use a table variable to save the query result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT string_agg([user_id] , ', ')
FROM 
(
    select cm.USER_ID
    from mytable cm 
    where cm.USER_ID = 'A' or USER_ID = 'B'
    group by cm.USER_ID
    having count(1) > 1
) DS ([user_id]);
```

Comment: what is DS ? not AS, sure?

Comment: @Hax It is alias of sub query.

Comment: why isn't it AS?

Comment: @Has you can write it as `AS DS` - and `DS` is short of `DataSource` - you can use valid name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @myquery TABLE( USER_ID NVARCHAR( MAX ) );

INSERT @myquery SELECT cm.USER_ID
                FROM mytable cm 
                WHERE cm.USER_ID = 'A' OR USER_ID = 'B'
                GROUP BY cm.USER_ID
                HAVING count(1) > 1;

SELECT string_agg( CAST(@myquery.USER_ID as NVARCHAR(MAX) ) , ', ' ) AS DuplicateList 
FROM mytable cm
INNER JOIN @myquery mq
    ON mq.USER_ID =  cm.USER_ID
```